# Install latest maven package in Ubuntu via apt package manager or other ways

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I am trying to install maven in linux machine using the following command:

```
sudo apt install maven
```

But this command installs the maven version 3.6.0, whereas the latest version for maven in the apache maven web-site is 3.8.1. Any suggestions on how to install maven 3.8.1 via apt install command or any else ways?

Comment: How did you check if it is 3.6.0 or 3.8.1 ?

Comment: By typing the command: mvn --version

Comment: Below solution works for you ?

Comment: This links helped me: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYfO26yc1EM)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a small guide to install maven on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Jul 28, 2021

1. Download maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
   click the link apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz.
2. Extract the files in your downloads folder.

   `cd Downloads`

   `sudo tar xzvf apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.tar.gz -C/opt/`
3. In a terminal window enter the following.

   `nano .profile`

Edit the file and add the following text at the bottom of the page.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

export JAVA_HOME

MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.1

export MAVEN_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH

export PATH
```

Now press ctrl + O to save the file, and ctrl + X to close the file.

4. Back in the terminal run the script with.

   `. .profile`

Check the version of java and maven with the commands.

```
`java --version`

`mvn --version`
```

Now you should see the proper version of Maven installed.

If you open a new terminal window and the installation seems ineffective: LOGOUT AND LOGIN!!!**

Comment: good answer. without using apt package manager.

Answer (score 6):

Following command helped me.

**Remove current version:**

```
sudo apt-get purge maven
```

**Download the latest version:**

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz
```

**Installation:**

```
sudo cp -r apache-maven-3.8.6 /opt
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin:$PATH
```

**Script**

```
#!/bin/sh

version=$1
if [ -z $version ] ; then echo "specify version" ; exit 1 ; fi

#Remove old maven
sudo apt-get purge maven -y

url="https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/${version}/binaries/apache-maven-${version}-bin.tar.gz"
echo $url
wget $url

sleep .4

tarFile="apache-maven-${version}-bin.tar.gz"
echo $tarFile
sudo tar -xvf $tarFile -C /opt/

export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-${version}/bin:$PATH
```

Pass the 1st argument as the maven version.
Example: `./install.sh 3.8.7`

***Note**: Make sure Java is installed before following the above steps.*

Answer (score 0):

Build it from the source. https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

> Installing Maven

---

1. Unpack the archive where you would like to store the binaries, e.g.:

```
Unix-based operating systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)
  tar zxvf apache-maven-3.x.y.tar.gz
Windows
  unzip apache-maven-3.x.y.zip
```

2. A directory called "apache-maven-3.x.y" will be created.
3. Add the bin directory to your PATH, e.g.:

```
Unix-based operating systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)
  export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.x.y/bin:$PATH
Windows
  set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.x.y\bin";%PATH%
```

4. Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK
5. Run "mvn --version" to verify that it is correctly installed.

For complete documentation, see https://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation

Answer (score -1):

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/ib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` should be
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`
which is the default Java 11 (OpenJDK) directory.